# Riemann's explicit formula for square-free numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-free

We know that for $x$ being a half-integer $$\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)=x-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}+O(1).$$
Is there a similar formula for $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)^2$ in the literature? The underlying Dirichlet series is $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ rather than $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$.

Comment: Yes, see this paper by Bartz from 1992, specifically Theorem 3: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002488116&physid=phys23#navi . The formula is more complicated than in the von Mangoldt case, and involves not only the zeros of the zeta function but the multiplicities as well.